# Кнопка, по нажатию которой запускается кнопка с другой Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, button

Создаю приложение, в которое встроил сканер QR-code. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на одной Activity, нажималась кнопка на другой Activity, либо по нажатию кнопки открывался сразу сканер.

[image: Activity1]

[image: Activity2]

Вот так я использую intent, чтобы перейти на другую Activity:

```
ImageButton scannerButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    scannerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.scannerButton);
    scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ScannerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Код самого сканера:

```
static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
}

// Запуск сканера qr-кода:
public void scanQR(View v) {
    try {

        // Запускаем переход на com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN с помощью intent:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        // Предлагаем загрузить с Play Market:
        showDialog(ScannerActivity.this, "Сканнер не найден", "Установить сканер с Play Market?", "Да", "Нет").show();
    }
}

// alert dialog для перехода к загрузке приложения сканера:
private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title,
                                      CharSequence message,CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            // Ссылка поискового запроса для загрузки приложения:
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

// Обрабатываем результат, полученный от приложения сканера:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Получаем данные после работы сканера и выводим их в Toast сообщении:
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Содержание: " + contents + " Формат: " + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ну и выполняйте в первой то же самое, что и во второй для запуска сканера (продублируйте метод scanQR()), зачем на какую то кнопку нажимать

Comment: @pavlofff, тогда и обработку надо дублировать. Не айс. Проще в первый интент выставить флаг, а получатель будет по нему "нажимать" кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

Ну так решите как Вам надо, сразу запускать сканер или перед этим стартовать второе Активити.

Запускаем сразу:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //дергаете свой метод scanQR(View v)
      scanQR(v)
    }
```

Запускаем второе Активити проверяем флаг и стартуем при необходимости

```
scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ScannerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isStartScan", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

В другом Активити проверяете есть ли флаг:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isStartScan", false)){
        scanQR(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: Я хочу запустить сразу сканер, я попробовал ваш код, но у меня метод "scanQR" подчеркивается красным.

Comment: scanQR - это ваш метод, который вы приложили к вопросу. Предполагаю что подчеркивается из-за того что он лежит в другом классе (втором Активити), если я прав, вам необходимо или создать объект класса второго Активити и вызвать его метод или скопировать метод  scanQR(v); первое Активити (в котором идет нажатие кнопки)

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо большое)